# How do I request my college google apps portal as a login source using Oauth2.0/OpenID and SecureSocial?

Tags: playframework-2.0, oauth-2.0, openid, google-apps, securesocial

I'm very new to Oauth / OpenID so I need some help. I'm building an application that if you want to register, you need to verify you're an active student. To do this, you need to:

1. select your college from a list and that will open a popup on screen with the login portal
2. sign in
3. if success, pop up closes and you're redirected to the next step of registration

My college uses a version of Google Apps for Education and the login is a Federated Identity Provider Login (not quite sure what that is but it says it). How do obtain the authorization url and the access token url for this process? Are there other things I need to do?

I'm a bit stuck so any advice, info or steps you could provide would be great. 
Cheers.

Here is the portal that I need to open. I used a website called Unidays. They do exactly what I'm trying to do, click a button, launches the portal, i log in, and i'm redirected back. If you type in that url, you can see the page yourself but it wont do anything. Is that the URL I may need?

[image: DCU Login Portal]

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I had the same issue and want to help other that may have it aswell.

The way I'm doing it on the site I'm working on is to make the oauth request as follows.

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?
response_type=code
&client_id={{YOUR CLIENT ID HERE}}
&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile
&redirect_uri={{WHERE ON YOUR SITE YOU WANT THE USER REDIRECTED AFTER LOGIN}}
&hd={{YOUR SCHOOLS GOOGLE APP NAME, PROBABLY dcu.ie}}
```

After the user logs in they will be redirected to the 'redirect_uri' with the get parameter 'code'. 
Of course you have to have your google api client setup first.